# Inform to another component that a button was clicked in a specific component

Tags: angular

How can I inform to my `home-day-component` that my user clicked on a button that are inside my `header-component` ? Both component's are inside the `home-component`

For example, if my user Click in the button `Previous Month`, the `home-day-component` need to know it.

**Home Component**

```
<header-component></header-component>
<div>
   <home-day-component></home-day-component>
</div>
```

**Header Component**

```
<nav class="nav" id="calendar">
   <button                                            
      (click)="previousMonth()">
   </button>
   {{current.month}} {{current.year}}
   <button                    
      (click)="nextMonth()">                    
   </button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a service with Subject,

You can create a subject inside your service

```
messageSource: Subject<string>;
```

and instantiate inside your constructor

```
this.messageSource = new Subject<string>();
```

in your component you can do this,

```
this.yourService.messageSource.next('whatvermessage');
```

and if you want to subscribe to it, you can do

```
this.yourService.messageSource.asObservable().subscribe((value: string) => {

});
```